# Problem with alter table big_table modify partition

Tags: oracle, partitioning, alter-table

I create table:

```
create table big_table(
  bt_id    number primary key,
  bt_date  date,
  bt_value varchar2(20)
)
```

Then I wnat partition this table (code abbreviated):

```
alter table big_table modify
  partition by range (bt_date)
  interval(numtoyminterval(1, 'MONTH'))
  subpartition by hash (bt_id)
  (
  partition nn_st_p1 values less than (to_date(' 2019-05-01 00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss'))
  subpartitions 4
  store in (ipr_tbl),
  )online
```

Error message:

```
17:20:39  line 1: ORA-14006: invalid partition name
```

I can't understand what is wrong with my partition name?

Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: Is your problem solved

Comment: Your example works for me in `19.0` (except for the syntax error in `store in (ipr_tbl),` which I suppose is cut&paste problem). In a comment you mentioned that the table *already has the wrong partitioning* - which is **not** what you are showing in the question. Could you post the exact DDL of the current table?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
CREATE TABLE big_table
  (bt_id       NUMBER PRIMARY KEY 
  , bt_date       DATE
  , bt_value   VARCHAR2(20)
  )
 PARTITION BY RANGE (bt_date) INTERVAL (NUMTOYMINTERVAL(1,'MONTH'))
 SUBPARTITION BY HASH (bt_id) SUBPARTITIONS 4
 (PARTITION nn_st_p1 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01-MAY-2019','dd-MON-yyyy'))
  )
PARALLEL;
```

Comment: I can't do that. 
My table comes with a lot of data, indexes, triggers and so on.
And also it already has the wrong partitioning.
I need to modify an existing partitioning for an existing table.

Duplicate a table, repartition, drop old table and then rename 
duplicate it is also not a good option for me for some reasons.

Comment: This (drop + create) is not an answer to the question "how to do an *alter table*"